# Unable to get RowUpdate Event Handler to display error for GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

The problem I am having is when I run the code I encounter this **error:**

> "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'OnHand', table
>   'C:\USERS\UNKNOWN\DESKTOP\XEX14PRODUCTRECEIPT\XEX14PRODUCTRECEIPT\APP_DATA\HALLOWEEN.MDF.dbo.Products';
>   column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails"

This happens when I edit the OnHand value to nothing or null, but I am supposed to get the error I created in the CodeBehind "A database error has occurred".

What is causing this?

Thank you!

### CodeBehind for GridView

```
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void grdProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grdProducts.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }
    protected void grdProducts_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception == null)
        {
            lblError.Text = "A databse error has occured. " + "Message: " + e.Exception.Message;
            e.ExceptionHandled = true;
            e.KeepInEditMode = true;

        }
        else if (e.AffectedRows == 0)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Another user may have updated that category. " + "Please try again ";
        }
    }
}
```

}

### Default.aspx

```
div class="container">
<header class="jumbotron"><%-- image set in site.css --%></header>
<main>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <asp:GridView ID="grdProducts" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                    CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdProducts_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ProductID"
                            ReadOnly="True">
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="col-sm-2" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" ReadOnly="True">
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="col-sm-6" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="OnHand" HeaderText="On Hand" SortExpression="OnHand">
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="col-sm-2 text-right" />
                            <ItemStyle CssClass="text-right" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                    </Columns>
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="bg-halloween" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altRow" />
                    <EditRowStyle CssClass="warning" />
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="bg-halloween" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HalloweenConnection %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT ProductID, Name, OnHand FROM Products" 
                    UpdateCommand="UPDATE Products SET OnHand = @OnHand WHERE (ProductID = @ProductID)">
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="OnHand" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>    
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p><asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server"  
                    CssClass="text-danger" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label></p>
                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" 
                    HeaderText="Please correct the following errors:" CssClass="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</main>
```

Comment: i think you have seted OnHand NOT Null in database remove that it will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically something like this happens in a database because of referential integrity, or because the column does not support information in it to be NULL.

In relational databases you want to make sure that the information you're updating is valid because the data may be used from one table to another.  In this case, changing one table's information will change many tables and having a NULL value would be kind of like having blanks in several tables.

I'm not entirely sure otherwise.. you may also be wanting to use a 'try/catch' block to catch an Sqlexception rather than an `if/else`. Inside the try catch block you can have an if/else to test the exception.

Something such as:

```
try
{
    //Whatever command you have executing your sql statement
}
catch(SqlException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.ToString());
}
```

I'd ensure you have code validating the input, ensuring the program doesn't attempt to execute code without having verified its the proper type of information to be inserted inside the database.